# SP13: Creating Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part, master-page

Is there a way to create a web part in SharePoint 2013 to avoid having to recreate the same web part to apply to different pages?

Issue:  I created a content web part that had taken me a long time to do.  Now, I have to apply it to a lot of pages.  I was thinking the best way to do is by creating a web part that would be available in the list of web parts to choose from.

Is this the best way to go about doing this?  Or, is there a easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did create it as a content editor web part, then you should be able to export it. Once exported, It can be uploaded to the web part gallery and then used in many places.

Comment: Thank you @Eric Alexander.  How do you export it?

Comment: If you go into edit mode on the page, the little ellipsis or dropdown arrow in the upper right of the web part, there should be an option to Export.

Comment: Is the only way to upload the web part to the gallery by using Designer?  Thanks again

Comment: it should be available in Site Settings, Web Part Gallery.